# Laravel updating a table value

Tags: mysql, laravel

I am working in laravel5.4. In my view page i have a list which contain a status. If the is_notified is disable i want to make it enable by clicking a button. please tell me the best way to do it.

```
enter code here

 @foreach($publishers as $publisher)
  <ul class="list-group">
       @if($publisher->pivot->is_notified===1)
           <li class="list-group-item list-group-item-success">
                {{$publisher->name}}<span class="pull-right">Notified</span>
            </li>
        @else
             <li class="list-group-item list-group-item-danger">
            {{$publisher->name}}<span class="pull-right">not notified</span>
             </li>
        @endif
    </ul>
  @endforeach
```

Comment: how about using ajax?

Comment: Where is your code?

Comment: Its my first project in laravel. I have column is_active which is zero when disable and is one when enable. I want the best way to do that

Comment: i just use a foreach loop and print the values

Answer (score 0):

1) create a button that links to a route with the id of the publisher you want to notify as parameter.

```
<a href="{{ url('/publisher/'.$publisher->id) }}">
   <button">View Slip</button>
</a>
```

2) create the route

```
 Route::get('/publisher/{id}', 'PublishersController@enable');
```

3) in your controller i.e PublishersController.php, get the id

```
public function enable ($id) {

   $publisher = Plusher::where('id', $id)->first();
   $publisher -> is_notified = "enable"
   $publisher -> save();

}
```